# Has anyone ever set up any code repository to deploy(upload) javascript/css/html files to SharePoint upon merge request approval or similar?

Tags: javascript, git, sharepoint, gitlab, devops

I'd like to see what other SharePoint Developers are doing with their DevOps practices.

**SharePoint version**: 2016 on-premise

Comment: Is [this](https://automate.io/integration/github/microsoft-sharepoint) along the lines of what you want to do?

Comment: Yes Thank you for sharing @David784 !